# Tab autocomplete adding \ to files after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: bash

I am new to Ubuntu and I hope this is a simple issue. When using terminal I normally hit TAB to autocomplete the file name but now its adding \ characters in the name. This never happened before when I was using Lubuntu 16 and only started after upgrading to 20.04. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

example:
**Your Personal Channel Line-Up.pdf**
turns into below when I type Y and TAB
**Your\ Personal\ Channel\ Line-Up.pdf**

Comment: Generally, backslashes are added to protect special characters from being interpreted by the shell. Can you [edit] your question to give examples of filenames where this is happening?

Comment: I added an example. I have been using Lubuntu 16 for months and never had this issue.  Thanks

Comment: This has been normal behavior for bash completion of *filenames containing spaces* for as long as I can remember - otherwise the completed name would be subject to word splitting by the shell when used in an actual command. You could begin the name as `'Y` (with a leading quote character) in which case it will complete as `'Your Personal Channel Line-Up.pdf'` (with a trailing quote character) instead of backslash-escaping the individual spaces.

Comment: Thank you for the information.  Adding the " before TAB works for commands like cp but not for ebook-convert (Calibre), which is still adding the \.  Maybe I should create a different issue for that?